# Can't send an array of Javascript objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ember.js, express

I have the following code

```
app.get('/posts',function(req,res){

console.log(posts);
res.send(posts);
res.send(200);
});
```

And i am using the following to get and return the array of js objects (posts is the array)

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return $.ajax({
        url : '/posts',
        type : 'GET',
        success : function(data){
            return data;
        }
    });
}
});
```

So when i populate the `posts` array with `[ { body: "Hello" }, {body : "world" } ]` , i get the following output in console :

[image: Output of node console]

Whereas in my app, the model is not rendered, moreover i can't see any response in chrome dev tools, these are some ss

[image: Chrome SS]

Response is Empty, not even `{}` . What is going wrong? I dont think there is anything with `Ember` , after all i can't see the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem occurs because you call `res.send` twice. Just comment this line:

```
res.send(200);
```

This line is not needed because Express automatically sets status code as `200` (or in some occasions - `304`).

If you want to set your own status code, just write:

```
res.status(someCode);
```

as you can read [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.status).

Comment: but will it work if use `res.send(200)` and `res.json(obj)` one after another?

Comment: @user206032 i believe not will not. but you can also write either `res.json(200, obj);`, or `res.send(200, obj);`

Answer (score 1):

A few problems:

1. You need to JSON.stringify your object before you send it.
2. Try to use this instead of res.send:

   ```
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
   res.end(JSON.stringify(posts));
   ```
3. Where are you trying to return 'data'? You should have some callback function there, like this:

   ```
   success:function(data) {
       handleData(data); 
   }
   ```

Comment: the data is returned as model for postsRoute, it is Ember